# How do I create a Silverlight application in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

I need to create a Silverlight application in VS 2008 for Win CE 6.0.
I installed VS 2008 SP1 and the Silverlight 2 SDK, and then Silverlight Tools for 2008.

However, when I open VS 2008, it's asking two options as follows:

1. Add a new ASP.NET web project to the solution to host Silverlight
2. Automatically generate a test page to host Silverlight at build time

I don't know which one I have to select if I want to build my application using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the silverlight output to an existing C# application, it's probably better to choose the second option. You don't need a complete ASP.NET webapplication.

Comment: i opened sample application in vs2008 but it was showing error that Requested Registry access not allowed what we have to for that

Comment: I can't say anything about that error. But what happens if you try to create a new Silverlight project with test page?

Comment: when we open vs2008 default pages will come right ie. app.xaml & page.xaml . in that pages in 1st line the above error coming starting itself

Comment: this is the 1st time im working with this can you give any link for knowing basic steps how to work

Comment: 'Requested Registry access not allowed' is the exact error message? http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/4041.aspx or http://www.osherove.com/blog/2009/5/27/fix-requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed-error-when-crea.html

Comment: hello sir i executed that cmd file as you mentioned earlier as administrator but after logoff i opened as user again i got the same error wt cn i do for that